# Lane detection in a Binary Image (formed by cloud points)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

I have been trying to detect lanes in Binary Image which I created using point clouds but for some reason I am not able to get it right. Below is the input Image

[image: Input Image]

This is the image I get after using canny

[image: Canny Edges]

But the final Image after Hough transform doesn't looks good. I tried changing the parameters but that didn't help much.

```
img = cv2.imread('cp.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred,10,150,apertureSize = 3)
cv2.imwrite('canny_image.jpg',edges)
cv2.waitKey(0)
minLineLength = 1
maxLineGap = 5
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,1,np.pi/180,200,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for arr in lines:
 x1,y1,x2,y2 = arr[0]
 cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255), 4)

cv2.imwrite('hough.jpg',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Final iMAGE]

Comment: Try changing the parameters `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap`, it should work. Otherwise, try `morphological operations`.

Comment: You binary images be looking smooth to you, but on close examination, there seems to be small breaks in the line formation, I would suggest to apply some Morphology Operations to join the distant white pixels to get better results.